# Using any kind of multiprocessing always results in an "EOFError: Ran out of input" or "can't pickle" error

Tags: python, pycharm, multiprocessing

So here's the deal: I need a Monte-Carlo simulation to ensure a sensor is as accurate as specified.
Problem, it's painfully slow. I won't get into details but I need to do a lot of maths behind the scenes. On top of that, I have to test 1M+ times to get accurate results, and we end up with easily 2h+ of calculation time alone, which obviously isn't really nice.

So, I've been looking around for some sort of parallelism, and multi-processing felt like the perfect solution.

Thus, I tried to pull some code [from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), as follows...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

...but of course,

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x0000026124EDA3B0>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Visibly, somehow, `p.start()` causes this. Which, surprised me at first, especially from a code snippet coming directly from the docs.

Anyways, I kept looking and trying out some snippets I could find here and there, but no matter what, I'd keep getting the same two errors.

And I just don't get why?
What am I missing out?

Here's the entire error log, from trying to run the snippet above.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:\DEV\SYMETRIE\v4\testMP1.py", line 13, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x0000026124EDA3B0>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

---

### Quite the big edit

As it turns out, this is a problem with PyCharm (my IDE of choice) and has been a known bug for now 3 years. Using another IDE fixes this issue. I guess it's time to change my workflow a little bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your error, on either Python 3.8 or 3.10.
Is it possible that you are encountering a formatting error?

Comment: @thom747 out of curiosity, I've decided to check if this issue was occuring when using an other IDE, and... it didn't. You'd think paying 250$/y for an IDE wouldn't have these problems but somehow it does... and has... for 3 years...

Comment: Interesting, I am also using PyCharm and do not have this problem. Regardless, I'm glad to hear you have found a solution.

Comment: It's a problem with the PyCharm _debugger_, based on the traceback. Don't run your code with the debugger?

Comment: @AKK if there's someone who doesn't run their code with a debugger here, trust me, it's me. For the worse and the best, sadly. I did find a solution to fix this, I'll add it to this post.

Comment: FWIW - Your code runs without error in both normal and debug modes using PyCharm 2023.3.2 with Python 3.12.1 on Apple Silicon M2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Turns out, PyCharm (the IDE) was the issue.

And I found a fix!
Head over to your configurations -> Edit -> turn off "Run With Python Console".
It's fixed!

For those who can't find it, it's [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCXfe.png)